# High Chart progress bar/Status bar

Tags: highcharts

I was trying to implement progress bar/status bar in HighChart, but some how highchart axis line not able to remove from the chart, tried with gridlinewidth grid line color but still the axis line shows up in the UI. is there any attribute to remove this

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="highchart.js"></script>
<script src="exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 210px; max-width: 300px; height: 50px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script>
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickColor: '#FFFFFF',
            tickWidth: 1,
            categories: [''],
            labels:{
                        enabled: false
                }
        },
        title:{
            text:''
        },
        yAxis: {
             gridLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
             minorGridLineWidth: 0,
             lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
             gridLineWidth: 0,
             title: {
                text: ''
             },
             labels:{
                    enabled: false
             }
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        legend:{
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
                enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: '',
            data: [5]
        }, {
            name: '',
            data: [5]
        },{
            name: '',
            data: [0]
        }]
    });
</script>
<style>
.chart-container .highcharts-grid {
   display: none;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't override an `!important` property. Thus you have to customize root css file of highchart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When chart type is set to `bar`, axes are reversed, try:

```
xAxis: {
     visible: false
},
yAxis: {
     visible: false
},
```